# PhpStorm and Jira integration

Tags: task, phpstorm, jira

Due to Atlassian IDE Connector is outdated, trying to use build in Task management system.

Adding server:[image]

And then trying to browse tasks but getting error:

`Cannot connect to https://*.atlassian.net Request failed. Reason: "Field 'summary' does not exist or this field cannot be viewed by anonymous users." "Field 'assignee' does not exist or this field cannot be viewed by anonymous users." "Field 'resolution' does not exist or this field cannot be viewed by anonymous users."`

Maybe someone faced similar problem?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Just checked today, no errors and everything working fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue today. It started occurring when i tried to mark Update issue state to "In Progress" [image]

From that point on every time i tried to work with this task or add new ones i got similar error messages.

The only solution that i could find was to remove the already affected tasks first. [image]

And after that uncheck "Update issue state" in "Open Task" options.
[image]

Unfortunately now there is no way to influence task status from PHPStorm.

It's a temporary solution at best, hopefully Atlassian does something about this soon.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a workaround for such an issue. It's working for me, however it's not perfect or handy in any way. phpStorm is collecting JIRA issue data somehow (it allows you to search thru the issue acronyms and lets you pick up one issue to time tracking). However with the problem which is occuring right now it's not possible for phpStorm to gather/update new issue data from connected projects to your account.

The workaround is to open the Atlassian Connector settings, JIRA Server section, when you have your credentials entered, just press "Test Connection". Probably it will report an error, but, surprisingly for me, task list in phpStorm is updated, new tasks appear...

Please try it, maybe this will work for you too?

Comment: At least for IDEA they didn't!

Answer (score 0):

Thought I would put a solution on this page found it in Chinese and it's really quite embarrassing I missed this as well.

The below is the ending point for working on a task which will give you the option to commit changes, merge branches, and yep Update Issue State.

Tools > Tasks & Context > Close Active Task... (Alt + Shift + W)